# Is there a way to extract a column subtotal from a matrix with DAX in Power BI?

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I created a matrix showing the number of parts made over the course of several months. The matrix shows the total values of all the parts failed on the column to the right. I want to get those values using DAX for filtering. Is there a way to get those values?

Matrix:

[image: Matrix]

I tried to get all the count of the part numbers but didn't work successfully

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options...

Remove the date context from the table (using `ALLSELECTED` instead of `ALL`, incase you want to apply outside filters on date like this year).

```
Part total A =
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Parts),
    ALLSELECTED(Parts[Date])
  )
```

Remove all context from the table except for `Parts[Id]` - this is more flexible than above and still respects any outside filters applied.

```
Part total B =
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Parts),
    DISTINCT(Parts[Id]),
    ALLSELECTED(Parts)
  )
```